# How can i receive my message in my activity Broad cast receiver?

Tags: android-contentprovider

I want that there be a broad cast receiver which has been registered inside class activity, and as soon as New SMS comes to my phone then that activity should be call, where i can also abord this broad cast receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register new Broad Cast receiver in your activity.